# Binary Lifting | Planet Queries 1 | TLE

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I am solving [this problem on CSES](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1750/).

> Given n planets, with exactly 1 teleporter on each planet which teleports us to some other planet (possibly the same), we have to solve q queries. Each query is associated with a start planet, x and a number of teleporters to traverse, k. For each query, we need to tell where we would reach after going through k teleporters.

I have attempted this problem using the **[binary lifting concept](https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/lca_binary_lifting.html)**.

1. For each planet, I first saved the planets we would reach by going through 2<sup>0</sup>, 2<sup>1</sup>, 2<sup>2</sup>,... teleporters.
2. Now, as per the constraints (esp. for k) provided in the question, we need only store the values till 2<sup>31</sup>.
3. Then, for each query, starting from the start planet, I traverse through the teleporters using the data in the above created array (in 1) to mimic the binary expansion of k, the number of teleporters to traverse.

> For example, if k = 5, i.e. (101)<sub>2</sub>, and the initial planet is x, I first go (001)<sub>2</sub> = 1 planet ahead, using the array, let's say to planet y, and then (100)<sub>2</sub> = 4 planets ahead. The planet now reached is the required result to the query.

Unfortunately, I am receiving TLE (time limit exceeded) error in the last test case (test 12).

Here's my code for reference:

```cpp
#define inp(x) ll x; scanf("%lld", &x)

void solve()
{
    // Inputting the values of n, number of planets and q, number of queries.
    inp(n);
    inp(q);

    // Inputting the location of next planet the teleporter on each planet points to, with correction for 0 - based indexing
    vector<int> adj(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &(adj[i]));
        adj[i]--;
    }

    // maxN stores the maximum value till which we need to locate the next reachable plane, based on constraints. 
    // A value of 32 means that we'll only ever need to go at max 2^31 places away from the planet in query.
    int maxN = 32;

    // This array consists of the next planet we can reach from any planet. 
    // Specifically, par[i][j] is the planet we get to, on passing through 2^j teleporters starting from planet i.
    vector<vector<int>> par(n, vector<int>(maxN, -1));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        par[i][0] = adj[i];
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < maxN; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            ll p1 = par[j][i-1];
            par[j][i] = par[p1][i-1];
        }
    }

    // This task is done for each query.
    for(int i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        // x is the initial planet, corrected for 0 - based indexing.
        inp(x);
        x--;
        // k is the number of teleporters to traverse.
        inp(k);

        // cur is the planet we currently are at.
        int cur = x;

        // For every i'th bit in k that is 1, the current planet is moved to the planet we reach to by moving through 2^i teleporters from cur.
        for(int i = 0; (1 << i) <= k ; i++)
        {
            if(k & (1 << i))
            {
                cur = par[cur][i];
            }
        }

        // Once the full binary expansion of k is used up, we are at cur, so (cur + 1) is the result because of the judge's 1 - based indexing.
        cout<<(cur + 1)<<endl;
    }
}
```

The code gives the correct output in every test case, but undergoes TLE in the final one (the result in the final one is correct too, just a TLE occurs). According to my observation the complexity of the code is O(32 * q + n), which doesn't seem to exceed the 10<sup>6</sup> bound for linear time code in 1 second.

Are there any hidden costs in the algorithm I may have missed, or some possible optimization?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: The `ll` in code stands for `long long`

Comment: `%d` isn't the right format specifier for reading a `long long`.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Yes, that was an error. I have corrected the code now, the issue is still the same however.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like your code works (after fixing the scanf), but your `par` map could have 6.4M entries in it, and precalculating all of those might just get you over the 1s time limit.

Here are a few things to try, in order of complexity:

1. replace `par` with a single `vector<int>` and index it like `par[i*32+j]`.  This will remove a lot of double indirections.
2. Buffer the output in a `std::string` and write it in one step at the end, in case there's some buffer flushing going on that you don't know about.  I don't think so, but it's easy to try.
3. Starting at each planet, you enter a cycle in <= n steps.  In O(n) time, you can precalculate the distance to the terminal cycle and the size of the terminal cycle for all planets.  Using this information you can reduce each k to at most 20000, and that means you only need j <= 16.